# gcc.exe cannot find -lglfw3 when using glfw-rs

Tags: windows, gcc, rust

I'm running Rust on Windows (probably my first mistake, but i'm not giving up) with mingw. I downloaded 64bit everything and when I build my project I get

```
error: linking with `gcc` failed: exit code: 1
note: gcc '-Wl,--enable-long-section-names' '-fno-use-linker-plugin' '-Wl,--nxcompat' '-static-libgcc' '-m64' '-L' 'C:\R
ust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib' '-o' 'C:\Users\jay\projects\hello_world\target\hello_world.exe' 'C:\Users\jay
\projects\hello_world\target\hello_world.o' '-Wl,--gc-sections' 'C:\Users\jay\projects\hello_world\target\deps\libglfw-5
007f9fddc425da6.rlib' 'C:\Users\jay\projects\hello_world\target\deps\libbitflags-57b03d5337bba57b.rlib' 'C:\Users\jay\pr
ojects\hello_world\target\deps\libsemver-693b3d5412b8e4b9.rlib' 'C:\Users\jay\projects\hello_world\target\deps\liblog-4e
79c2d7625e8c6f.rlib' 'C:\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc
-windows-gnu\lib\libcollections-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libunicode-4e7c5e5c.rlib'
'C:\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librand-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\lib
alloc-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liblibc-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-p
c-windows-gnu\lib\libcore-4e7c5e5c.rlib' '-L' 'C:\Users\jay\projects\hello_world\target' '-L' 'C:\Users\jay\projects\hel
lo_world\target\deps' '-L' 'C:\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib' '-L' 'C:\Users\jay\projects\hello_world\.rust
\bin\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu' '-L' 'C:\Users\jay\projects\hello_world\bin\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu' '-Wl,--whole-archive' '-W
l,-Bstatic' '-Wl,--no-whole-archive' '-Wl,-Bdynamic' '-lglfw3' '-lopengl32' '-lgdi32' '-lws2_32' '-lcompiler-rt'
note: ld: cannot find -lglfw3

    error: aborting due to previous error
    Could not compile `hello_world`.
```

(Tried to format it but..?)

I believe the problem is my gcc.exe, it says cannot find input file whenever i run it. Is there a gcc.exe i can replace it with?

Comment: “note: ld: cannot find -lglfw3”: I’m presuming this means you need libglfw3 object files or source code handy.

Comment: What command are you running? I didn't think that GCC would be required for normal Rust compilation.

Comment: @Shepmaster im running cargo build

Comment: I assume that this isn't just a standard "Hello World", is it? [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/) is an OpenGL library. Are you using some extra crates or anything like that? Can you provide us a [MCVE](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can investigate more?

Comment: @Shepmaster what's mcve? and im using gl-rs

Comment: @JayHall ugh. My link was mis-formatted in my previous comment:  [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try downloading the [precompiled GLFW libraries](http://www.glfw.org/download.html). I copied the files from the `lib-mingw` directory into my Rust project. On my 32-bit Windows VM, I put them in `hello-glfw\bin\i686-pc-windows-gnu`, but it looks like you want `hello_world\bin\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`. This allowed me to run the [example from the glfw-rs README](https://github.com/bjz/glfw-rs).

Comment: Thanks, it works! The directory you were talking about was in Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu . I'm not sure if I was supposed to but i used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC6Axj1MNEQ to add libs and stuff to minigw.

Comment: I don't think you should add project-specific libraries to your global path. In your output in the question, there's the line `'-L' 'C:\Users\jay\projects\hello_world\bin\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu'`. This means that a project-specific directory is already being searched for these libraries; it's probably much safer to keep things there! What if you wanted multiple versions of this library for different projects?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I need to start taking notes on these kind of things.

Comment: Hold up, the bin folder isn't in my project directory. Just src target and some other files

Comment: That's right. Create `bin` next to `src` and the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` inside of that.

Comment: Unless you have it in your path, you have to put the dll by the exe too.

Comment: In my case I had to copy everything in `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\rust\tools\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib` because I installed minGW with chocolatey