# Linking with a Windows library outside the build folder

Tags: windows, rust, ffi

Is there a way to link with a library that's not in the current package path.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545958/ffi-example-from-book-cannot-find-lanneclib-under-windows) suggests placing everything under the local directory. Our packages are installed in some repository elsewhere. I just want to specify the libpath to it on windows.

```
authors = ["Me"]
links = "CDbax"

[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.CDbax]
rustc-link-lib = ["CDbax"]
rustc-link-search = ["Z:/Somepath//CPP/CDbax/x64/Debug/"]
root = "Z:/Somepath//CPP/CDbax/x64/Debug/"
```

But trying cargo build -v gives me

```
package `hello v0.1.0 (file:///H:/Users/Mushfaque.Cradle/Documents/Rustc/hello)` specifies that it links to `CDbax` but does not have a custom build script
```

From the cargo [build script support](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#overriding-build-scripts) guide, it seems to suggest that this should work. But I can see that it hasn't added the path. Moving the lib into the local `bin\x68_64-pc-windows-gnu\` path works however.

**Update**
Thanks to the answer below, I thought I'd update this to give the final results of what worked on my machine so others find it useful.

In the Cargo.toml add

```
links = "CDbax"
build = "build.rs"
```

Even though there is no build.rs file, it seems to require it (?) otherwise complains with

```
package `xxx v0.1.0` specifies that it links to `CDbax` but does not have a custom build script
```

Followed by Vaelden answer's create a 'config' file in .cargo

If this is a sub crate, you don't need to put the links= tag in the parent crate, even though it's a dll; even with a 'cargo run'. I assume it adds the dll path to the execution environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are mistaking the *manifest* of your project with the *cargo
configuration*.

- The *manifest* is the `Cargo.toml` file at the root of your project. It describes your project itself.
- The *cargo configuration* describes particular settings for cargo, and allow for example to override dependencies, or in your case override build scripts. The *cargo configuration files* have a [hierarchical structure](http://doc.crates.io/config.html#hierarchical-structure):

> Cargo allows to have local configuration for a particular project or
>   global configuration (like git). Cargo also extends this ability to a
>   hierarchical strategy. If, for example, cargo were invoked in
>   /home/foo/bar/baz, then the following configuration files would be
>   probed for:
>
> ```
> /home/foo/bar/baz/.cargo/config
> /home/foo/bar/.cargo/config
> /home/foo/.cargo/config
> /home/.cargo/config
> /.cargo/config
> ```
>
> With this structure you can specify local configuration per-project,
>   and even possibly check it into version control. You can also specify
>   personal default with a configuration file in your home directory.

So if you move the relevant part:

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.CDbax]
rustc-link-lib = ["CDbax"]
rustc-link-search = ["Z:/Somepath//CPP/CDbax/x64/Debug/"]
root = "Z:/Somepath//CPP/CDbax/x64/Debug/"
```

to any correct location for a cargo configuration file, it should work.