# kiss3d build error: the trait 'core::fmt::Debug is not implemented for the type Modifiers

Tags: rust

I have tried to build "kiss3d"  under windows 7 (rust 1.0 32bit, rust nighty 1.3 32bit ) but without success. Has anybody done it, with success?

I used the following Cargo.toml :
 Cargo.toml 
(accord.:
   [gcc.exe cannot find -lglfw3 when using glfw-rs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183497/gcc-exe-cannot-find-lglfw3-when-using-glfw-rs)):

```
[package]
name    = "kiss3d"
version = "0.1.2"
authors = [ "SĂ©bastien Crozet <developer@crozet.re>" ]

description = "3D graphics engine for Rust."
repository = "https://github.com/sebcrozet/kiss3d"
readme = "README.md"
keywords = [ "3D", "graphics", "OpenGL", "KISS" ]
license = "BSD-3-Clause"

include = [
    "src/**/*.rs",
    "examples/**/*.rs",
    "examples/media",
    "examples/Cargo.toml",
    "Cargo.toml",
    "LICENSE",
    "Readme.md"
]
    [dependencies.glfw]
    git = "https://github.com/bjz/glfw-rs.git"
    default-features = false

   [lib]
    name = "kiss3d"
    path = "src/lib.rs"

   [dependencies]
    nalgebra = "*"
   gl = "*"
   time = "*"
   num = "*"
   libc = "*"
   ncollide_procedural = "*"
   freetype-rs = "*"
   image = "*"
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may wish to read [ask]. Specifically, you've given very little detail about how to reproduce your problem. I would expect to see a `Cargo.toml` file that shows your dependencies and a [MCVE](/help/mcve) that could be used as a `main.rs` that would have the same error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I found what works for me ( using Win 7 prof, rust nightly 1.4 32bit version):

1)  I have changed the lib.rs  in ./src directory adding the following line:
       #![feature(libc)] 
     before the line: 
      extern crate libc;

2)  I have create ./bin/i686-pc-windows-gnu directory in the root of project

3)  In ./bin/i686-pc-windows-gnu i have copied the following files:
      freetype6.dll,glfw3.dll

4)  changed Cargo.toml:

```
 [package]
 name    = "kiss3d-examples"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [ "SĂ©bastien Crozet <developer@crozet.re>" ]
[dependencies]
rand = "*"
nalgebra = "*"
gl = "*"
time = "*"
num = "*"
image = "*"
ncollide_procedural = "*"
ncollide_transformation = "*"
freetype-rs = "*"
[dependencies.glfw]
git = "https://github.com/bjz/glfw-rs.git"
default-features = false
 [lib]
 name = "kiss3d"
 path = "./src/lib.rs"

 [[bin]]
 name = "cube"
 path = "./cube.rs"
```

So I was able to : cargo run  and the cube examples runs ...